# XPath - find parent from child value

Tags: xml, xpath

Need the xpath query to find element all element c's that have element t value of "string goes here"

```
<f>
  <c>john</c>
  <cr>100</cr>
  <lb>
    <l num="1">
      <d>12-FEB-2015</d>
      <ts>
        <t>string goes here</t>
```

Have tried several variations of

```
- "./c[./t=""string goes here""]"
```

Comment: In which language you want. c# or java

Comment: All `c` elements with child `t` elements containing _string goes here_, or any descendant `t`?

Comment: According to sample XML you posted, `t` is neither child nor descendant of `c`. Is that also the case in the actual XML?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with

```
"//c[.//t[.='string goes here']]"
```

Explanation:

- `//c`  a `c` element, doesn't matters where in the tree
- `.//t` with a child `t` element, does't matters how deep it is

The important concept here it's the `.` axis, representing the current context; in the `.//t` it keeps track of parent element context, looking for `t` elements inside it.

If you `t` element location is immutable, you can also do:

```
"//c[lb/l/tr/t[.='string goes here']]"
```